# Is there a way to get the Instance id of the EC2 instance using "Fn::GetAtt"?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I was working on a CFT template and currently in a situation where i will be needing instance id of the EC2 instance to use in the template. Is there a way to get the Instance id of the EC2 instance using "Fn::GetAtt"?

i searched for the parameters but didnt find a specific one for instance id.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-instance.html):

> When you pass the logical ID of this resource to the intrinsic *Ref*
> function, Ref returns the instance ID. For example:
> *i-1234567890abcdef0*.

You can also retrieve it with **Fn::GetAtt**:

> The *Fn::GetAtt* intrinsic function returns a value for a specified
> attribute of this type. The following are the available attributes and
> sample return values.
> [...]
> **Id**
> The ID of the instance.

Comment: "EC2InstanceId": {
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "vmInstance"
            }
        }
i am guessing this would be the right way to get instance id?

Comment: Yes, there's even an example with it in the Ref function docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html